# http: conditional get does not give a chance to refresh headers without sending body again

Tags: java, http, tomcat, apache2, http-headers

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature in the http spec, or I am not understanding things ok.

I have a resource that changes at most once a week, at the week's beginning. If it didn't change, then the previous week's resource continues to be valid for the whole week.

(For all our tests we have modified the one week period for five minutes, but I think our observations are still valid).

First we send the resource with the header `Expires: next Monday`. The whole week the browser retrieves from the cache. If on Monday we have a new resource then it is retrieved with its new headers and everything is ok.

The problem occurs when the resource is not renewed. In response to the conditional get our app (Java+Tomcat) sends new headers with `Expires: next Monday` but without the body.  But our frontend server (apache) removes this header, because the spec says you should not send new headers if the resource did not change. So now forever (until the resource changes) the browser will send a conditional get when we would like it to continue serving straight from the cache.

**Is there a spec compliant way to update the headers without updating the body? (or sending it again)**

And subquestion: how to make apache pass along tomcat's headers?

Comment: Is it really worth optimizing this far? Sending a body only once a week is already well optimized. Is the body so bandwidth-consuming?

Comment: you should show the headers from the response/request + response code, 304 response (not-modified) does not prevent use of new headers and it must include Date header, anyways.

Comment: @JBNizet I believe his problem is that the browser will now recheck on every access if the resource was modified, since it doesn't receive an updated "retry next monday". The browser just sees "the file is more than 7 days old, I have to retry". A workaround probably is to forcibly send it once a week, i.e. force it to have a "new" version every monday, even if it actually is identical.

Comment: @Anonymouse, checking is ok each time, a lot of browsers nowadays can dump cache each time they are stopped/started, so caching is an optimization hint you shall not rely too much. Checking each time is quite cheap if the client (browser) supports pipe-lining.

Comment: Well, in particular with modern web sites where resources change frequently anyway, caching is mostly of interest for session speedups. But probably not in his case. I guess the solution might however be to use a custom expiry model, outside of HTTP.

Comment: Are you using Apache as a reverse proxy cache, using mod_cache?

Comment: Also, could you provide the response-line/headers from Tomcat & Apache.

Comment: How is the Tomcat server connected to the Apache server?  mod_jk, Proxy Pass, ...?

Answer (score 5):

Just a `Expires` header is not enough. According to [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) section 13.3.4, a server needs to respond with two headers, `Last-Modified` and `ETag`, to do conditional GET right:

> In other words, the preferred behavior for an HTTP/1.1 origin server is to send both a strong entity tag and a Last-Modified value.

And if the client is HTTP/1.1 compliant, it should send `If-Modified-Since`. Then the server is supposed to respond as following (quoted from Roy Fielding's [proposal to add conditional GET](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/websoft/caching.html)):

- If resource is inaccessible (for whatever reason), then the server should return a 4XX message just like it does now.
- If resource no longer exists, the server should return a 404 Not Found response (i.e. same as now).
- If resource is accessible but its last modification date is earlier (less than) or equal to the date passed, the server should return a 304 Not Modified message (with no body).
- If resource is accessible and its last modification date is later than the date passed, the server should return a 200 OK message (i.e. same as now) with body.

So, I guess you don't need to configure Apache and/or Tomcat the way you described. You need to make your application HTTP/1.1 compliant.

Comment: Refer to section 10.3.5 of RFC 2612. It says that what's required is ETag and Date, and You can include Expires, Cache-control and/or Vary.

Comment: "Preferred behavior" doesn't mean it's a requirement. You don't need to send ETag headers for If-Modified-Since to work correctly.

Comment: @RickNZ You're right, yes. ```ETag``` is not mandatory but recommended. More HTTP/1.1-ish, if you will. That's also why I said 'needs to' not 'must'.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a valid [HTTP-Date](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1) for the [Expires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) header?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is using separate URIs for each week. The canonical url redirects to the appropriate url for the week, and instructs the browser to cache the redirect for a week. Also, URLs that have a date in them will instruct the browser to cache forever.

**Canonical URL : /path/to/resource**

```
Status Code : 301
Location : /path/to/resource/12-dec or /path/to/resource/19-dec
Expires : Next Monday
```

**Week 1 : /path/to/resource/12-dec**

```
Status code : 200
Expires : Never
```

**Week 2 : /path/to/resource/19-dec**

```
Status code : 200
Expires : Never
```

When the cache expires on Monday, you just send a redirect response. You either send last weeks URL or this weeks, but you never send the entire response body.

With this approach, you have eliminated conditional gets. You have also made your resources "unmodifiable-once-published", and you also get versioned resources.

The only caveat - redirects aren't cached by all browsers even though the http spec requires them to do so. Notably IE8 and below don't cache. For details, [look at the column  "cache browser redirects" in browserscope](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top).

Answer (score 0):

The `Expires` header was basically deprecated with HTTP 1.1; use `Cache-Control: max-age` instead.

Make sure you are including `Last-Modified`.

It's optional, but you may also want to specify `Cache-Control: must-revalidate`, to make sure intermediate proxies don't deliver potentially stale content.

You don't need to set `ETag`.

Example request:

```
GET http://localhost/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5
Referer: http://localhost/default.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The response includes the requested content:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=10
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Sat, 21 Feb 2009 11:28:18 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sun, 18 Dec 2011 05:48:34 GMT
Content-Length: 2245
```

Requests made before the 10 second timeout are resolved from cache, with no HTTP request. After the timeout:

```
GET http://localhost/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5
Referer: http://localhost/default.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
If-Modified-Since: Sat, 21 Feb 2009 11:28:18 GMT
Host: localhost
```

The response is just headers, without content:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=10
Last-Modified: Sat, 21 Feb 2009 11:28:18 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sun, 18 Dec 2011 05:49:04 GMT
```

Subsequent requests are again resolved from the browser's cache until the specified cache expiration time.